# Full height TimeMarker in react-timeseries-charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, time-series

I am trying to modify the cycling example from the react-timeseries-charts repository. I would like to add vertical lines that span across all rows (much like the cursor tracker does).

I have added the TimeMarker component to the charts array:

```
charts.push(
    <LineChart
        key={`line-${channelName}`}
        axis={`${channelName}_axis`}
        series={series}
        columns={[channelName]}
        style={style}
        breakLine
        interpolation={"curveStepAfter"}
    />
);
charts.push(
    <TimeMarker
        time={4500}
    />
);
```

This displays a vertical line on all plots as expected however the line doesn't span the full height of each ChartRow so visually looks disjointed (see image).

I have tried playing around with each of the props on TimeMarker but can't find any that alter the line height and can't find anything in the docs either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

P

edit: image upload doesn't seem to work, hopefully it's clear what I mean. There's about 10px of whitespace between each chart row where I would like the line to continue to produce a single joined up vertical line across all rows.